# Invalid property 'environmentId' of bean class. Bean property 'environmentId' is not readable or has an invalid getter method

Tags: spring, jsp

I am returning model object in backend.I am trying to create drop down data from backend to front end..But i am getting not readable exception..

This is my code...

```
public class Customer {
private Environments envrironmentId;
private Environments environmentName;
 getters and setters
}
```

This is my controller layer.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/environments",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getenvironments(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response,@ModelAttribute("customer") Customer customer,@RequestParam String selectedcustomername) throws Exception{
        System.out.println("selected cust name"+selectedcustomername);
        ModelAndView model = null;  
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        List<org.mvc.domain.Environments> environmentNames = loginDelegate.getEnvironments(selectedcustomername);
        Collections.sort(environmentNames, new CustomComparator());

        for(int i=0;i<environmentNames.size()-1;i++){
            customer.setEnvrironmentId(environmentNames.get(0));
            customer.setEnvironmentName(environmentNames.get(1));
        }
        map.put("environmentNames", environmentNames);
        model = new ModelAndView("welcome", "map", map);
        return model;

    }
```

This is my Ui..

```
<form:form method="get" action="retrieve" modelAttribute="customer" commandName="customer">

    <b>Environment:</b>
                            <form:select path="environmentId" id="environmentDetails">                                                                                                                                                  
                            <option selected="selected">Select An Environment</option>
                            <form:options items="${map.environmentNamesList}" itemLabel="environmentName" itemValue="environmentId"/>                                                                                                                                                       
                            </form:select>
                         </td>
```

This is my error..

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'environmentId' of bean class [org.mvc.domain.Customer]: Bean property 'environmentId' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
```

can any one help me

Comment: Your field is named `envrironmentId` not `environmentId`.

Comment: just its a type mistake .,.

Comment: Please show your getters and setters (and fix your typo, then most probably the error will be gone).

Comment: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter? If you read this error you will be able understand the problem. check the bean getter method for the field environmentId